# For NUMBER columns in Oracle, does specifying a length help performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any true difference in performance between NUMBER, NUMBER(3) and NUMBER(10)? Doesn't the RDBMS use 32 bits to store the value regardless, and simply limit the length of the data when looked at as a string?

A colleague debated that it was, for example, more efficient to use NUMBER(10) vs NUMBER/NUMBER(11), thinking that *n* was the number of bytes rather than the length of the data in characters. Normally I'd agree to limit the column size if the number of rows was guaranteed not to exceed 10^n or so, but for this particular database the limit for number of rows was literally "as many as possible", e.g. 2^32 or ~4 billion, even though we'd never reach that amount. Coming up with a "lowest maximum" for this situation seems pointless and a waste of time and I thought using NUMBER without specifying a length would be simpler and incur no penalties. Am I correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically, you don't define a length, but a precision and scale.

The same numeric value (eg 100, 4.3) takes the same internal value irrespective of the precision and scale defining the column.

The maximum value a column can hold is determined by BOTH precision and scale. That is you can store the value 100 in a column of NUMBER(3,0) but not in a column of NUMBER(3,1).

Generally, if a column shouldn't store a decimal the scale should be zero. Bear in mind that if you try to store 10.12 in a NUMBER(3,0) it will store the value 10. It doesn't error (because if it did, you'd have a hard time storing the value of one third in anything). If you want it to error you want to allow for a higher scale and use a constraint to stop it ever being used.

I also believe that you should try to use a 'sensible' precision too. If you stored a thousand values each second for a thousand years you'd still fit that within 14 digits. If I see a column of NUMBER(14,0) then I know that on my screen or printout I should allow for 14 numeric characters to be displayed. If I see just NUMBER or NUMBER(38,0), then I haven't really been given any guidance and may guess at 14 characters. And if they start putting 16 character credit card numbers in there, I'll be wrong. Which is why I prefer not to guess.

Also in PL/SQL, they have a PLS_INTEGER datatype which goes up to 2147483647. If I see a column of NUMBER(9,0) I know I can fit it into a PLS_INTEGER. There's probably similar considerations for Java or .Net etc. when they want to work out what datatype, scale, precision to use when pulling/pushing data to the database.

Comment: +1 - specifying scale and precision is about good design, not performance.

Answer (score 8):

It makes no difference wheter you use `NUMBER(1)` or `NUMBER(10)`. The storage requirements are the same and depend on the data that you store in it.

The only possible difference in performance is between `NUMBER()` and `NUMBER(N)` because the latter will have to check the size while storing. But that is so negligible that it is probably not even measurable.

Comment: +1.  I've heard so many people argue over how they think Oracle SHOULD work when it only takes a minute to test this.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the 32 bits - no.  In Oracle the NUMBER type is a variable length base-10 floating point value with a guaranteed precision of 38 digits.  See [the Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A81042_01/DOC/server.816/a76965/c10datyp.htm) and [this AskTom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1619552483055).

<*soapbox*>

In fact, I think NUMBER is actually one of *The Best Things* in Oracle.  I've read a truism to the effect that "any product (language, database, etc) that requires developers to know and care about the number of bits in a numeric variable are unfit for business programming" and agree with it completely.  There is **no** reason for someone writing accounting software to give a hoot about whether or not their value will fit into a 32-bit scaled decimal, or whether double-length ANSI floats might cause a problem (they will), or a myriad of other issues which revolve around the issue of numbers in computers.  Numbers are too important to be too efficient about.  YMMV.

<*/soapbox*>

Share and enjoy.